# How to ensure that the form is refilled with the old values only if the insertion failed the last time?

Tags: php

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert Item - SomuFinance</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexStyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="addItemContainer">
        <h1>Insert Item</h1>
        <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <div class="leftAligned">
                <?php
                    $save_vals = FALSE;
                    if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
                    {
                        $shop = $_POST['shop'];
                        $category = $_POST['category'];
                        $item = $_POST['item'];
                        $qnty = $_POST['qnty'];
                        $unit = $_POST['unit'];
                        $price_based_on = $_POST['price_based_on'];
                        $mrp = $_POST['mrp'];
                        $sellers_price = $_POST['sellers_price'];
                        $last_updated_on = $_POST['last_updated_on'];
                        $save_vals = $_POST['save_vals'];
                    }
                ?>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="shop">Shop : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="shop" name="shop" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $shop;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="category">Category : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="category" name="category" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $category;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="item">Item : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="item" name="item" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $item;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="qnty">Quantity : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="qnty" name="qnty" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $qnty;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="unit">Unit : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="unit" name="unit" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $unit;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="price_based_on">Price based on : </label>
                    <select name="price_based_on" id="price_based_on">
                        <option value="kilos" <?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){if($price_based_on=='kilos'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Kilos</option>
                        <option value="packet" <?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){if($price_based_on=='packet'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Packet</option>
                        <option value="bottle" <?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){if($price_based_on=='bottle'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Bottle</option>
                        <option value="box" <?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){if($price_based_on=='box'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Box</option>
                        <option value="piece" <?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){if($price_based_on=='piece'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Piece</option>
                    </select>
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="mrp">MRP (₹) : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="mrp" name="mrp" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $mrp;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="sellers_price">Seller's Price (₹) : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="sellers_price" name="sellers_price" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $sellers_price;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="last_updated_on">Last Updated on : </label>
                    <input type="date" id="last_updated_on" name="last_updated_on" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $last_updated_on;} else echo date("Y-m-d") ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inp">
                <input id="insertButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert">
            </div>
            <div id="message">
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                    {
                        $shop = $_POST['shop'];
                        $category = $_POST['category'];
                        $item = $_POST['item'];
                        $qnty = $_POST['qnty'];
                        $unit = $_POST['unit'];
                        $price_based_on = $_POST['price_based_on'];
                        $mrp = $_POST['mrp'];
                        $sellers_price = $_POST['sellers_price'];
                        $last_updated_on = $_POST['last_updated_on'];
                        $result=null;

                        $dbc =  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','atlantis2016','itemDB')
                                    or die("Error Connecting to Database");

                        $query = "INSERT INTO grocery VALUES ('0', '$shop', '$category', '$item', '$qnty', '$unit', '$price_based_on', '$mrp', '$sellers_price', '$last_updated_on')";

                        if(!empty($shop)&&!empty($category)&&!empty($item)&&is_numeric($qnty)&&!empty($unit)&&is_numeric($mrp)&&is_numeric($sellers_price)&&!empty($last_updated_on))
                        {
                            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                                                or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
                        }

                        if($result)
                        {
                            echo '<span class="success">Item Inserted Successfully!</span>';
                            $_POST['save_vals']=FALSE;  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<span class="failure">Failed to insert Item.</span>';
                            $_POST['save_vals']=TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#message").fadeIn(400);
                });
                </script>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to determine whether to load the previously posted values if the operation was unsuccessful - otherwise not. If i were to simply set the value of $save_vals at the end of the script, they wouldn't exist at the beginning the next time the page is loaded. So I tried manually setting `$_POST['save_vals']` so that it is available the next time the page is loaded. But I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: save_vals in E:\wamp\www\SomuFinance\insertItem.php on line 27

Line 27 is : `$save_vals = $_POST['save_vals'];`
What am I doing wrong? How do I ensure that the previous values are loaded ONLY IF the insertion was unsuccessful?

**EDIT** : While the use of a hidden input type solves the undefined problem, how do I ensure that the form is refilled ONLY when the insertion failed the last time?

Here's my updated code after using an input of hidden type:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert Item - SomuFinance</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexStyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="addItemContainer">
        <h1>Insert Item</h1>
        <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <div class="leftAligned">
                <?php
                    $save_vals = FALSE;
                    if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
                    {
                        $shop = $_POST['shop'];
                        $category = $_POST['category'];
                        $item = $_POST['item'];
                        $qnty = $_POST['qnty'];
                        $unit = $_POST['unit'];
                        $price_based_on = $_POST['price_based_on'];
                        $mrp = $_POST['mrp'];
                        $sellers_price = $_POST['sellers_price'];
                        $last_updated_on = $_POST['last_updated_on'];
                        $save_vals = $_POST['save_vals'];
                    }
                ?>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="shop">Shop : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="shop" name="shop" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $shop;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="category">Category : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="category" name="category" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $category;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="item">Item : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="item" name="item" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $item;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="qnty">Quantity : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="qnty" name="qnty" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $qnty;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="unit">Unit : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="unit" name="unit" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $unit;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="price_based_on">Price based on : </label>
                    <select name="price_based_on" id="price_based_on">
                        <option value="kilos" <?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){if($price_based_on=='kilos'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Kilos</option>
                        <option value="packet" <?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){if($price_based_on=='packet'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Packet</option>
                        <option value="bottle" <?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){if($price_based_on=='bottle'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Bottle</option>
                        <option value="box" <?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){if($price_based_on=='box'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Box</option>
                        <option value="piece" <?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){if($price_based_on=='piece'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Piece</option>
                    </select>
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="mrp">MRP (₹) : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="mrp" name="mrp" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $mrp;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="sellers_price">Seller's Price (₹) : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="sellers_price" name="sellers_price" value="<?php if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $sellers_price;} ?>">
                </div> <br>
                <div class="inp">
                    <label for="last_updated_on">Last Updated on : </label>
                    <input type="date" id="last_updated_on" name="last_updated_on" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); if((!empty($_POST['submit']))&&($save_vals)){echo $last_updated_on;} else echo date("Y-m-d") ?>">
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="save_vals" name="save_vals">
            </div>
            <div class="inp">
                <input id="insertButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert">
            </div>
            <div id="message">
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                    {
                        $shop = $_POST['shop'];
                        $category = $_POST['category'];
                        $item = $_POST['item'];
                        $qnty = $_POST['qnty'];
                        $unit = $_POST['unit'];
                        $price_based_on = $_POST['price_based_on'];
                        $mrp = $_POST['mrp'];
                        $sellers_price = $_POST['sellers_price'];
                        $last_updated_on = $_POST['last_updated_on'];
                        $result=null;

                        $dbc =  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','atlantis2016','itemDB')
                                    or die("Error Connecting to Database");

                        $query = "INSERT INTO grocery VALUES ('0', '$shop', '$category', '$item', '$qnty', '$unit', '$price_based_on', '$mrp', '$sellers_price', '$last_updated_on')";

                        if(!empty($shop)&&!empty($category)&&!empty($item)&&is_numeric($qnty)&&!empty($unit)&&is_numeric($mrp)&&is_numeric($sellers_price)&&!empty($last_updated_on))
                        {
                            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                                                or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
                        }

                        if($result)
                        {
                            echo '<span class="success">Item Inserted Successfully!</span>';
                            $_POST['save_vals']=FALSE;  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<span class="failure">Failed to insert Item.</span>';
                            $_POST['save_vals']=TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#message").fadeIn(400);
                });
                </script>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to set `save_vals` as an `input` element with a `hidden` type. The `$_POST` is populated with the `input` elements of the form. The indices come from the `name`s of the elements.

Comment: You don't have any `name` attribute with the text `some_vals`,

Comment: you haven't set a name into your input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @chris85 What am I doing wrong? How do I ensure that the previous values are loaded ONLY IF the insertion was unsuccessful? Even the use of a hidden input doesn't solve this. This part of the question remains unanswered. Please help.

Comment: @chris85 How would you suggest I do this so that the desired effect is reached?

Comment: Use a `SESSION` then you wont need the `save_vals` either. You can have states saved, `failed` and `submitted`. Once `submitted` don't display it anymore, if `failed` output `POST` values and the form again.

Comment: @chris85 would you please show me an example in an actual answer so that I can upvote it?

Comment: I can't currently, or I could but I cant test it so I'd prefer not to. If theres nothing posted tomorrow I'll throw something up. You should be using parameterized queries, this is open to SQL injections. With the `php_self` you also are open to XSS injections.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` isn't persistent between loads, the same as `$save_vals`, it only contains elements submitted by the form. So you would either need to add an input to the form with `<input type="hidden" name="save_vals" value="<?php echo $save_vars; ?>">` or use session variables e.g. `$_SESSION['save_vars']`

Comment: I'm already using an input of hidden type. But it still doesn't work. Check my answer for an updated code.

Comment: Try adding a `value="true"` to the hidden input

Comment: Now the value sticks even if the entry is correct. It's supposed to clear the fields (i.e., not load the old values) if that happens.

Comment: Just change it to `value="false"` then I misinterpreted it as keep the values in the fields

Comment: Now the values don't clear out even if the insertion is successful!

Comment: Scratch that, You'll need to replace the line `$_POST['save_vals']=FALSE;` with the HTML Code to print the hidden input with `value="false"`, and likewise for `$_POST['save_vals']=TRUE;`

Comment: I'm sorry, but it didn't. I had to change the code and go to jQuery validation.